# Assign value to Variable and call in multiple commands

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I need to assign a value to variable from select query output and call the variable into sql commands

For eg: I get PDB_NAME from v$pdbs and assign value to v_pdb
        I want to use v_pdb in multiple sql commands to run against PDBs

I tried to assign value from SELECT query to v_pdb and call the v_pdb in 'alter session set container=v_pdb';, it looks like working, but i get ORA-00922: missing or invalid option error

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
v_sql varchar2(80);
v_pdb varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  FOR pdb IN (select name from v$pdbs where con_id=3 and OPEN_MODE='READ WRITE') 
  LOOP
    v_sql := 'alter session set container='||pdb.name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    --execute immediate 'alter session set container='||pdb.name||';';
    execute immediate v_sql;
    --v_sql := 'show con_name';
    --execute immediate 'show con_name';
    --execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'create tablespace APPDATA datafile '+DATA' size 1G autoextend on next 100M maxsize 5G ENCRYPTION USING 'AES256' DEFAULT STORAGE (ENCRYPT)';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'drop user bigschema cascade';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    --execute immediate 'drop user bigschema cascade'; 
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'create user bigschema identified by B67_kuca_ecdf default tablespace APPDATA temporary tablespace TEMP profile DEFAULT account unlock';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'alter user bigschema quota unlimited on APPDATA';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'grant dba to bigschema';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'conn bigschema/"B67_kuca_ecdf"@'||pdb.name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'drop table MV2OCI';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'create table MV2OCI tablespace APPDATA as select * from dba_objects';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'alter table MV2OCI nologging';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'show user';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'insert into MV2OCI select * from dba_objects';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
    v_sql := 'insert into MV2OCI select * from MV2OCI';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing: ' || v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I simply want to get the value for variable v_pdb from "select name from v$pdbs where con_id=3 and OPEN_MODE='READ WRITE'"

And call the v_pdb as follows:

alter session set container=v_pdb;
run other sql commands
...
......

Comment: Try `v_pdb := pdb.name;` as the first line of your loops body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the trailing semi-colon in your dynamic SQL.  Dynamic SQL does not include a trailing semi-colon -- since the dynamic SQL is a single statement, no statement-separator is required.

After dropping the trailing semi-colon (and the "show" command (a client command)) this works ok.  But I don't know of a good way to get `DBMS_OUTPUT` going unless you are already in a given PDB.  That has been dropped in this example.

```
declare
    v_sql varchar2(80);
BEGIN
    FOR pdb IN (select name from v$pdbs where con_id=3 and OPEN_MODE='READ WRITE')
        LOOP
            v_sql := 'alter session set container='||pdb.name;
            execute immediate V_SQL;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
            v_sql := 'CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(LOREM_IPSUM NUMBER)';
            execute immediate V_SQL;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Result:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Navigating over to the PDB, `TEST_TABLE` now exists there.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't look like working with show con_name command
I need to run multiple SQL statements after i set "alter session set container=pdb;"
I get error when replace select * from dual to show con_name
            v_sql := 'show con_name';
 
/SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
Executing: alter session set container=PDB1D002
Executing: show con_name
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-06512: at line 11

Comment: Thanks user918753.  "SHOW" is a sqlplus/sqlcl command -- sqlplus/sqlcl see "show" and actually run other commands to gather other information to display in the terminal.  SQLPlus commands can't be run in dynamic SQL, only valid SQL or PL/SQL can be executed in an `execute immediate` block.  You could instead run a valid SQL statement to get the connection name and do whatever is needed with it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it actually has anything to do with your pdb variable...

When you use execute immediate you can not have a ; in the string

So for each of your execute immediate statments remove the ; eg

```
execute immediate 'alter session set container='||pdb.name||';';
```

becomes

```
execute immediate 'alter session set container='||pdb.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to improve the code and the coding process:

1. **Exclude statement terminators from dynamic SQL:** As others have mentioned, remove the `;` from the end of SQL statements used in dynamic SQL.
2. **Escape strings:** Strings in strings need to be escaped.  The string `'DATA'` should be `''DATA''`.
3. **Pay attention to the full error message:** Always display the *entire* error message, including the line number and column number.  That information points exactly to the problem.
4. **Use the smallest possible example:** A [smaller example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) would have less errors, making it easier to find the real problem.  And in the process of simplifying the example you will likely find the answer yourself.